# Formatting Date Error - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Trying to write a SQL query to format a date output, but I am getting an error stating, 'a non-numeric character was found where a numeric is expected.'

Below is my SQL:

```
SELECT e.emp_num, emp_lname, emp_fname, sal_amount
FROM LGEMPLOYEE e
JOIN LGSALARY_HISTORY sh ON e.emp_num = sh.emp_num
WHERE sal_from = (SELECT MIN (to_date(sal_from,'dd-mon-yy'))
                FROM LGSALARY_HISTORY sh 
                WHERE sh.emp_num = e.emp_num)
ORDER BY e.emp_num;
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the data type of `sal_from`?  Is it a `varchar2`?  A `date`?  Something else?

Comment: @JustinCave the data type is varchar2. Example of the data is '09-NOV-11'

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
MIN (to_date(sal_from,'dd-mon-yy'))
```

with

```
TO_CHAR(MIN (to_date(sal_from,'dd-mon-yy')), 'dd-mon-yy')
```

You're trying to compare VARCHAR2 with a DATE. Oracle uses an implicit types conversation using the following rule:

> When comparing a character value with a DATE value, Oracle converts
>   the character data to DATE.

Just an assumption: Oracle is trying to convert sal_from to a DATE using default NLS settings (session or database) and apparently fails (because the default date format is 'dd-mm-yy' for example)

Comment: I replaced my line with your line and getting an error stating: 'unexpected end of sql command'

Comment: @AznDevil92 Sorry, lost 1 parentheses

Comment: Thank you for your input. SQL query runs but no rows returned. That means something is wrong with my data...i believe

Comment: @AznDevil92 I'd recommend to use another table alias in the correlated subquery (where you're getting min), other then "sh" because you have the same in the parent query. But I don't think the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

This is why it's never a good idea to store date values in a `varchar2` column.  There is at least one row in your table where the character string in `sal_from` isn't in the format you expect.  That's causing the `to_date` call to throw an error.

One way of isolating the problematic rows would be something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_valid( p_str IN VARCHAR2, p_mask IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  l_date     DATE;
BEGIN
  l_date := to_date( p_str, p_mask );
  RETURN 'Y';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    RETURN 'N';
END;
```

and then

```
SELECT *
  FROM lgsalary_history
 WHERE is_valid( sal_from, 'dd-mon-yy' ) = 'N'
```

Comment: After creating the function and running the select statement it states no data found

Comment: @AznDevil92 - Are you saying that you are getting a `no_data_found` error?  Or that the `select` statement doesn't return any rows?  Is the `emp_num` in both tables a `number`?  Or is one of the two a `varchar2`?

Comment: Select statement doesn't return any rows. This is no error.